# An extenstion method for a WPF control is causing an StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, wpf, extension-methods

Here's my extension method:

```
public static void SetThreadSafeProperty<T>(this System.Windows.FrameworkElement control, Expression<Func<T>> property, T value)
{
    if (control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        var del = new SetThreadSafePropertyDelegate<T>(SetThreadSafeProperty);
        control.Dispatcher.Invoke(del, control, property, value);
    }
    else
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = GetPropertyInfo(property);
        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            propertyInfo.SetValue(control, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm calling it:

```
tbManufacturer.SetThreadSafeProperty(() => tbManufacturer.Text, "test");
```

After debugging it, it looks like it gets stuck in an infinite loop. CheckAcess() is true and it creates the deletegate just fine and invokes correctly. But it keeps going and going and eventually fails.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Run it with breakpoints in the debugger and see if the problem becomes evident.

Comment: It should be the other way round: `if (!control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got your condition the wrong way round - `CheckAccess()` will return `true` when it's *okay* to modify the object in the current thread.

Currently, you're saying, "If I'm already in the UI thread, call the method again in the UI thread" - which obviously causes problems. You want to say "If I'm *not* in the UI thread, call the method again in the UI thread" - so your code should be:

```
if (!control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
```

Comment: Ah, yeah. I am converting a WinForm library to WPF and the InvokeRequired property has the opposite effect. It works. thanks!